# Redirect stereo sounds through a mono channel

Tags: pulseaudio

My amp's right channel broke down, and these songs in this perfect album I want to listen to just don't do left-channel-only.

How can I downmix stereo audio to mono?

SSH-ing via laptop into my audio PC, running Fedora 20. Standard onboard audio out.

Comment: There are a few similar questions over on Super User Stack Exchange: [Mono sound output in Ubuntu?](//superuser.com/questions/657876/mono-sound-output-in-ubuntu), [Force downmix to mono on Linux](//superuser.com/questions/155522/force-downmix-to-mono-on-linux). — And a similar one on Ask Ubuntu: [Can I downmix stereo audio to mono?](//askubuntu.com/questions/17791/can-i-downmix-stereo-audio-to-mono)

Comment: thanks i'll take a look. Thanks editors of the question as well, much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it with https://askubuntu.com/a/72076

Basically make a mono sink, then redirect playback to it with pacmd.